# Android 4.4 Kit Kat list selector color

Tags: android, themes, android-4.4-kitkat

Since Android 4.4 Kit Kat, pressed buttons or selected list items are no longer highlighted blue, but a translucent grey shade. Does anybody know what color the new list selector is or how I might be able to find out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [new episode of Android Design in Action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QHkv-bSlds&feature=c4-overview-vl&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF), new selector is a black overlay with 10% alpha.

Comment: 10% black overlay (at 9m50secs in the video)

Answer (score 6):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#1A000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#77000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

Comment: Can you provide a source?

Comment: for what you need source ?

Comment: I would like know to where these color values come from. Did you find them in Android source code or are those just guesses? Just pasting a piece of code without providing any comments is not enough in this case.

Comment: @Natix as written in above comment `According to the new episode of Android Design in Action, new selector is a black overlay with 10% alpha.` I applied the values nothing else. I thought it is sufficient to provide the code only as it's obvious from code, what it'll do.

Comment: Why #77000000 for the focused state ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis `77` is `10%` opacity and `000000` is black color for focused stated you can skip this.

Comment: 77 is 119 in base 10, so 46%.

Comment: @StephaneMathis do you have any documentation reference for your statement, becoz i don't know any stating that, if yes please share it here i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Documentation for what ? 77 in base 16 is 119 in base 10, so way more than 10% for 255.